# HTML in Pidgin conversations

Tags: plugins, pidgin, html

Is there a plugin or hidden feature in Pidgin that parses HTML in chats? I couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @LyndenShields Nope. This was for Hipchat which has a nice desktop app now, so I'm not using Pidgin for this anymore. Sorry :\

Comment: that's my exact use case. Trying to avoid having multiple chat clients. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin itself has a widget it calls "GtkIMHTML" or similar, which is used for the chat windows. It, as most chat services do these days, supports a subset of HTML for conversations, which is used for embedding images and such. It is however, not a full HTML/Browser engine.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer! How can I enable this feature so it parses all messages? For example, when someone writes `<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>` I want to see the actual link, not the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

***DeWYSIWYGification Plugin 2.6.3*** does what you wish. It can be reached via the pidgin-plugin-pack, usually installed via Synaptic and in the majority of the cases pre-installed with Pidgin itself.

[image]

After installing, simply enable in the "Plugins" section. It has nothing configurable but will work exactly as you wish...

[image]

Unfortunately, it only works uni-directional towards your contacts. Which means that your contacts will receive the links you send (as in your example to @dobey's comment) or any other html code you send.

I am sorry if this doesn't fix your need to "receive html" but I post this answer just if you find it useful.

Good luck!

Comment: Nice! But as you said, it works exactly in the opposite direction :(